# Ternary String - finding recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

A. Find a recurrence relation for the number of ternary strings of length *n* that contain two consecutive 2s.

B. Use this recurrence relation to compute the number of ternary strings of length 5 that contains two consecutive 2s(not 0s or 1s).

How do I go about and solve this problem step by step as I don't have any idea on how to start it.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the first related question on the list on this page.

Comment: Can there be a more clear explanation aside from that? I'm really new to this topic and I don't get it at all.

Comment: I think the accepted answer to the duplicate question is about as clear as possible. If you don't understand it you could ask a new question pointing to the first place in that argument that troubles you. Just saying "I don't get it all all" is not likely to get you more help. Before you tackle this recursion, make sure you understand simpler ones.